# Json string not finding controller method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-5

Using a third party plugin for javascript, fullcalendar. One of the options is a dayClick event, which is pretty obvious on what it does.  As soon as a day is clicked it performs an action.

So I got ajax in this dayClick function and I'm trying to pass a value to the controller.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        height: 170,
        selectable: true,
        editable: true,
        defaultView: 'basicWeek',
        dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {

            $.ajax(
            {

                url: '@Url.Action("Calendar","Home")',
                type: "GET",
                data: JSON.stringify({ date: date }),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    $("calendarLoad").append($(response));
                    $('#myModal').modal();
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    alert(error);
                    alert(status);
                    alert(request.responseText);
                }
            });


        }
    });

});
```

If it successfully passes its supposed to write out my partial view. But it doesn't get to this point. I've debugged my controller and the `date` parameter is null.

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Calendar(string date)
    {

        string[] dateSplit = date.Split(new char[] { 'T' });

        DateTime objDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dateSplit[0]);

        var content = db.Calendars.Where(x => x.startDate == objDate).ToList();



        return PartialView(content);
    }
```

I'm using fiddler to monitor the results after using the dayClick function and I see it trying to pass the JSON data but the result is always [image]

No results.

Answer (score 0):

It should just be:

```
    data: { date: date },
```

without any call to `JSON.stringify()`. jQuery will convert that object into the appropriate form for the HTTP request. When you pass it a string, it assumes that you've already done the conversion so it just uses the string directly (as you can see in that URL you highlighted in the screenshot).

Comment: I'm still not getting any results unfortunately. I have my fullcalendar javascript code written in my index page. But I'm trying to pass data to my partial view Calendar and then load it afterwards.

Is this logic possible, by passing data from the ActionResult Index method (the GET) to my ActionResult Calendar(GET). 

Not really familiar with how javascript interacts with C#.

Comment: @JoshBarber well I'm not an ASP.NET user so I'm not sure. Heck for all I know ASP may *want* the JSON. It looks like your HTTP request is getting some sort of error; maybe you can check server-side logs or something like that.